# How to solve TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, typeerror

i get this following error

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Here is my code

```
def draw_homography_points(img, x, resize=256, color=(255,0,0)):
    y_start1 = (0.3+x[2])*(resize-1)
    y_start = 0.3*(resize-1)
    y_stop = resize-1
    src = np.float32([[0.45*(2*resize-1),y_start],[0.55*(2*resize-1), y_start],[0.1*(2*resize-1),y_stop],[0.9*(2*resize-1), y_stop]])
    dst = np.float32([[(0.45+x[0])*(2*resize-1), y_start1],[(0.55+x[1])*(2*resize-1), y_start1],[(0.45+x[0])*(2*resize-1), y_stop],[(0.55+x[1])*(2*resize-1),y_stop]])
    dst_ideal = np.float32([[0.45*(2*resize-1), y_start],[0.55*(2*resize-1), y_start],[0.45*(2*resize-1), y_stop],[0.55*(2*resize-1),y_stop]])
    [cv2.circle(np.assarray(img), tuple(idx), radius=5, thickness=-1, color=(255,0,0)) for idx in src]
    [cv2.circle(np.assarray(img), tuple(idx), radius=5, thickness=-1, color=(0,255,0)) for idx in dst_ideal]
    [cv2.circle(np.assarray(img), tuple(idx), radius=5, thickness=-1, color=(0,0,255)) for idx in dst]
    return img
```

the error occur on the last 4 line [cv2.circle....]

i try to change cv2.circle(np.assarray(img) into cv2.circle(np.float32(img) but the problem is not solved. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: on what line does the error occur?

Comment: what is `numpy.assarray`?

Comment: thx for your reminder. i forgot to put the error line. @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: i'm using someone else code, so i don't really understand it :(